# get_or_create: is it a 'get' or a 'create'?

Tags: python, peewee

AFAIK, peewee's `Model.get_or_create()` doesn't return a flag that indicates a creation, unlike django's `get_or_create()`. Is there a good way to check if an instance returned by `get_or_create()` is freshly created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to source code, no way to find out. Also, according to documentation, it is not recommended to use this method.

I suggest to use try/except/else clause.

Comment: Yeah, don't use `get_or_create` -- it's deprecated and vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: @coleifer is it still deprecated?

Comment: @coleifer, Who said you that?

Comment: `get_or_create` is so gross :(  it's so  hard to get it right and so frequently people could write their own implementation much more simply.

Answer (score 2):

There's a section in the docs that should hopefully be helpful: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#get-or-create

If the docs are lacking, please let me know and I'll be happy to improve them.

Comment: If I wrap a call to `get_or_create()` inside a `db.transaction()` context, will it then be safe from race conditions?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.get_or_create

> classmethod get_or_create(**kwargs)

Attempt to get the row matching the given filters. If no matching row is found, create a new row.

Parameters:

- kwargs – Mapping of field-name to value.
- defaults – Default values to    use if creating a new row.

**Returns:**

- **Tuple of Model instance and boolean indicating if a new object was created.**

It also warns you that race conditions are possible with this method, and even gives you an example without using the method:

```
try:
    person = Person.get(
        (Person.first_name == 'John') &
        (Person.last_name == 'Lennon'))
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    person = Person.create(
        first_name='John',
        last_name='Lennon',
        birthday=datetime.date(1940, 10, 9))
```